# Why is QWebView ignoring CSS which browsers display without problems?

Tags: javascript, python, css, pyqt, google-visualization

I'm using a python script to build a javascript/html that shows a Google GeoChart in a UI. To display this i use a QWebView to load the html file (stored locally).

I wanted to take the borders off the markers in the GeoChart so they can layer better for a heatmap effect.

To do this, I have a line of CSS in my html header like so:

```
    <style>
        #geochart-colors > div > div > svg > g > g > g > g > circle {stroke-width: 0px}
    </style>
```

If I load the html file in Chrome, Firefox or IE it has removed the borders from the markers as I want:

[image: how the markers look in my browsers]

But in the QWebView in my UI, loading exactly the same html file keeps the borders on the markers:

[image: how they look in QWebView]

I tested to check if it was ignoring the CSS line entirely by adding a fill color amendment:

```
fill:#ff0000
```

to my CSS, and even in QWebView it works correctly and the fill color is changed.

So the QWebView seems to just be ignoring the `stroke-width` part of the CSS line. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the path to that element is using Chrome or FF dev tools? Then try manually adding a stroke in the browser.

Comment: Just tried this, and manually adding a stroke in the browser works fine, but saving this and loading through QWebView doesn't change stroke-width (that is, no change is detected by QWebView)

Comment: I suspect then it might be an issue of when the stroke gets applied. Maybe some style is being applied afterwards which overrides yours.